# Python-docx: Find-and-Replace while adding a hyperlink into Word file

Tags: python, replace, hyperlink, python-docx

Can I add a hyperlink while conducting a find-and-replace (i.e. make sure the word is in a single run, replace the word with another, and apply a hyperlink while doing so)?

I nearly got it working with the following code, but the "add_hyperlink_into_run" function is a bit dodgy as is, placing the the hyperlink in very strange places (before the run in question, after, the wrong link, or no hyperlink at all). I toyed with the i value in "paragraph._p.insert( i+3, hyperlink )" to get the hyperlinks as close as possible to their actual spot, but clearly I'm not understanding the basic code. I'm certain this is all uber-naive, not really being a programmer.

Thanks again for all your help!

```
import sys, os, random, re, copy
from docx import *


# Identify all paragraphs with a specific heading style (e.g. 'Heading 2')
def iter_headings( paragraphs, heading ) :
    for paragraph in paragraphs :
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith( heading ) :
            yield paragraph


def paragraph_replace_text( paragraph, regex, replace_str, addLink=True ) :
    """Return `paragraph` after replacing all matches for `regex` with `replace_str`.

    `regex` is a compiled regular expression prepared with `re.compile(pattern)`
    according to the Python library documentation for the `re` module.
    """
    
    # --- a paragraph may contain more than one match, loop until all are replaced ---
    while True :
        text = paragraph.text
        
        match = regex.search( text )

        if not match :
            break

        # --- when there's a match, we need to modify run.text for each run that
        # --- contains any part of the match-string.
        runs = iter( paragraph.runs )
        start, end = match.start(), match.end()

        # --- Skip over any leading runs that do not contain the match ---
        for run in runs :
            run_len = len( run.text )

            if start < run_len :
                break

            start, end = start - run_len, end - run_len


        # --- Match starts somewhere in the current run. Replace match-str prefix
        # --- occurring in this run with entire replacement str.
        run_text = run.text
        run_len = len( run_text )
        run.text = "%s%s%s" % ( run_text[ :start ], replace_str, run_text[ end: ] )
        end -= run_len  # --- note this is run-len before replacement ---


        # --- Remove any suffix of match word that occurs in following runs. Note that
        # --- such a suffix will always begin at the first character of the run. Also
        # --- note a suffix can span one or more entire following runs.
        for run in runs :  # --- next and remaining runs, uses same iterator ---
            if end <= 0 :
                break

            run_text = run.text
            run_len = len( run_text )
            run.text = run_text[ end: ]
            end -= run_len


##    # --- optionally get rid of any "spanned" runs that are now empty. This
##    # --- could potentially delete things like inline pictures, so use your judgement.
##    for run in paragraph.runs :
##        if run.text == "" :
##            r = run._r
##            r.getparent().remove( r )
     

    return paragraph


def add_bookmark( paragraph, bookmark_text, bookmark_name ) :
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    tag = run._r

    start = oxml.shared.OxmlElement( 'w:bookmarkStart' )
    start.set( oxml.ns.qn( 'w:id' ), '0' )
    start.set( oxml.ns.qn( 'w:name' ), bookmark_name )
    tag.append( start )

    text = oxml.OxmlElement( 'w:r' )
    text.text = bookmark_text
    tag.append( text )

    end = oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:bookmarkEnd')
    end.set(oxml.ns.qn('w:id'), '0')
    end.set(oxml.ns.qn('w:name'), bookmark_name)
    tag.append(end)


def add_hyperlink_into_run( paragraph, run, link_to, text ) :
    runs = paragraph.runs
    for i in range( len( runs ) ) :
        if runs[ i ].text == run.text :
            break

    # create hyperlink node
    hyperlink = oxml.shared.OxmlElement( 'w:hyperlink' )
    
    # set attribute for link to bookmark
    hyperlink.set( oxml.shared.qn( 'w:anchor' ), link_to, )
    
    # set attribute for link to bookmark
    hyperlink.set( oxml.shared.qn( 'w:tooltip' ), 'Turn to ' + link_to, )
    hyperlink.append( run._r )
    paragraph._p.insert( i+3, hyperlink )

    
##def add_link( paragraph, link_to, text ):
##    # create hyperlink node
##    hyperlink = oxml.shared.OxmlElement( 'w:hyperlink' )
##
##    # set attribute for link to bookmark
##    hyperlink.set( oxml.shared.qn( 'w:anchor' ), link_to, )
##
##    # set attribute for link to bookmark
##    hyperlink.set( oxml.shared.qn( 'w:tooltip' ), link_to, )
##
##    new_run = oxml.shared.OxmlElement( 'w:r' )
##    rPr = oxml.shared.OxmlElement( 'w:rPr' )
##    new_run.append( rPr )
##    new_run.text = text
##    hyperlink.append( new_run )
##
##    r = paragraph.add_run()
##    r._r.append( hyperlink )
##    r.font.name = "Times New Roman"
##    r.bold = True
####    r.font.color.theme_color = MSO_THEME_COLOR_INDEX.HYPERLINK
####    r.font.underline = True


""" NOTE: Replace 'Doc.docx' with your filename """
# Open the .docx file
document = Document( 'Doc.docx' )


# Search document for unique placeholder entries (must have a unique heading style)
entryWorking = [] # The placeholder entries created for the draft gamebook


""" NOTE: Replace 'Heading 4' with your entry number header """
for heading in iter_headings( document.paragraphs, 'Heading 4' ) :
    entryWorking.append( heading.text )


# Create list of randomized gamebook entry numbers
entryNumbers = [ i for i in range( len ( entryWorking ) + 1 ) ]
entryNumbers.remove( 0 ) # Remove zero (extra added above to compensate)
entryNumbers = [ str( x ) for x in entryNumbers ] # Convert to strings

setNumbers = [] # container for pre-set entry numbers

# Identify pre-set entries (such as Entry 1), and remove from both lists
# This avoids pre-set numbers being replaced (i.e. they remain as is in the .docx)
# Pre-set entry numbers must _not_ have the "#" prefix in the .docx
for string in entryWorking :
    if string[ 0 ] != '#' :
        entryWorking.remove( string )
        entryNumbers.remove( string )
        setNumbers.append( string )

# Shuffle new entry numbers
random.shuffle( entryNumbers )


# Create new placeholders for bookmark links below
append_str = '#'
entryPlaceholders = [append_str + sub + append_str for sub in entryNumbers]


# Create list of tuples of placeholder entry, random entry, random entry placeholder
reference = list( zip( entryWorking, entryNumbers, entryPlaceholders ) )

# Replace placeholder headings with assigned randomized entry
for heading in iter_headings( document.paragraphs, 'Heading 4' ) :
    for entry in reference :
        if heading.text == entry[ 0 ] :
            heading.text = entry[ 1 ]


# Bookmark each entry for internal reference
for heading in iter_headings( document.paragraphs, 'Heading 4' ) :
    add_bookmark( heading, "", heading.text )


# Append set entries to end of reference list for the following operations
for i in setNumbers :
    reference.append( ( '☺', i, '#'+i+'#' ) )


# Replace placeholders in each paragraph with assigned randomised entry
for paragraph in document.paragraphs :
    for entry in reference :
        if entry[ 0 ] in paragraph.text :
            regex = re.compile( entry[ 0 ] )
##            paragraph_replace_text( paragraph, regex, entry[ 2 ] )
            paragraph_replace_text( paragraph, regex, entry[ 1 ] )


# Substitute hyperlink to bookmarks for each paragraph-level reference
for paragraph in document.paragraphs :
    for run in paragraph.runs :
        for entry in reference :
            if run.text == entry[ 2 ] :
                add_hyperlink_into_run( paragraph, run, entry[ 1 ], entry[ 1 ] )
##                add_link( newParagraph, entry[ 1 ], entry[ 1 ] )


# Save the new document with final entries
document.save('Output.docx')
```

Comment: Not easily unfortunately @Chimer1013. There is no API support for adding hyperlinks so you'd be on your own to get the XML structured the right way. If you can narrow down the problem you're having to a few lines of code we can probably help, but 200+ lines of code is too much of an ask for us to wade through. I highly recommend getting a specimen of working XML for this (a paragraph or a run I expect) and then dumping what you're producing with `print(paragraph._p.xml)` or `run._r.xml` and work from there. When they match, you should be done. Start by narrowing this down as much as possible.